# Requiring Images in Field Maps

Tags: arcgis-collector, arcgis-field-maps

I'm trying to find a way to require images (attachments) in Field Maps when a user submits a point. I have an ArcGIS Online account with a GIS Professional Standard license. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Our field workers regularly forget to take a picture before leaving the field. It’s such an easy mistake to make, but when they may be driving hundreds of miles to get on site, it’s a difficult thing to fix once they've returned home.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible yet, below is the esri community thread

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-field-maps-questions/requiring-a-photo-in-field-maps/td-p/1011845/page/2